# How to integrate $\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Could you help me solve this?
$$\iint_{M}\!\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\,dxdy;$$
$M: \frac{\pi^2}{4}\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4\pi^2$

I know that the region would look like this and I need to solve it as difference of two regions. Lets say $C=A\cup B$, then $A = C - B$

[image]

I was able to get the integrals, but don't know how to solve them.
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4\pi^2-x^2}}\!\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\,dydx - \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{4}-x^2}}\!\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\,dydx$$

Comment: This domain and this integrand call for polar coordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that

Comment: Do you mean you've never used polar coordinates variable change? Or you don't know how to do it in this case?

Comment: Look up *Jacobians*.  This describes how you change integration variables in multiple integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to polar coordinates. Thus $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ gets replaced by $r$. and $dx\,dy$ gets replaced by $r\,dr\,d\theta$.  So we end up needing to integrate $r\cos r\, dr\,d\theta$ over our region.

Note that the limits of integration for $r$ are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $2\pi$. If the region you are interested in is just the first quadrant region, as in the picture, then $\theta$ will run from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The integration with respect to $r$ is done using integration by parts. Let $u=r$ and $dv=\cos r\,dr$. Then $du=dr$ and we can take $v=\sin r$. So 
$$\int r\cos r\,dr=r\sin r-\int \sin r\, dr=r\sin r +\cos r+C.$$

**Added:** So for the first quadrant region, our integral is
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} \int_{r=\pi/2}^{2\pi} r\cos r\,dr\,d\theta.$$
The integration with respect to $\theta$ will be easy, since there is no dependence on $\theta$.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: You mean integration with respect to $\theta$? Whatever we got out of the first integration gets multiplied by the length of the $\theta$ interval, that is, by $\pi/2$. By the way, the first integration gives $1-\pi/2$, so the full integral is $(\pi/2)(1-\pi/2)$.

Comment: When I replace $\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ by $r$, how do I get $dx dy = r\,dr\,d\theta$? I mean, where does the $r$ come from on the right side?
This is how I tried to solve the integral you have added http://mathb.in/5012 ... Thank you!

Comment: In $2$-variable calculus, you may have bumped into the Jacobian. The $r\,dr\,d\theta$ is also discussed in $1$-variable calculus, under area in polar coordinates. Your integration $\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\pi/2)\,d\theta$ may be incorrect. We are integrating a **constant**. The antiderivative is $(1-\pi/2)\theta$, now plug in.

Comment: Just a question please, why not taking the intergal over $\theta $ from $0$ to $2\pi $?